# vue cli run serve is ValidationError:

Tags: vuejs3, vue-cli

ValidationError: Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialized using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.

- configuration.output.chunkFilename: A relative path is expected. However, the provided value "/src/js/[name].js" is an absolute path!
  - configuration.output.filename: A relative path is expected. However, the provided value "/src/js/[name].js" is an absolute path!
  Please use output.path to specify absolute path and output.filename for the file name.
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mj31B.png)

when i run npm run serve
is there any solution about this?